Google Cloud Workflows: decode protobuf payload
I am defining a Google Cloud Workflow using a .yaml file. I need it to listen to documents being saved to Firestore, via eventarc.
The trigger works fine but I am not able to decode the protobuf message and can't find documentation on how to do it anywhere.
This is a sample message I get:
{
  "data": "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",
  "database": "(default)",
  "datacontenttype": "application/protobuf",
  "dataschema": "https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents/blob/main/proto/google/events/cloud/datastore/v1/data.proto",
  "entity": "products/0rO536qqGwsG7UHKSRsc",
  "id": "8da5a03c-3779-4d46-be20-546841cbaa8c",
  "location": "europe-west1",
  "namespace": "(default)",
  "project": "firecms-demo-27150",
  "source": "//firestore.googleapis.com/projects/firecms-demo-27150/databases/(default)",
  "specversion": "1.0",
  "subject": "documents/products/0rO536qqGwsG7UHKSRsc",
  "time": "2024-04-02T23:08:27.862367Z",
  "type": "google.cloud.datastore.entity.v1.created"
}

And my yaml file looks something like:
main:
  params: [event]
  steps:
      - extract_data:
          assign:
            - data: # How do I decode a protobuf from the given message??
          
      - create_document:
            call: googleapis.firestore.v1.projects.databases.documents.patch
            args:
                name: ${name}
                body:
                    fields:
                        test_new_field:
                            stringValue: abc

Thank you in advance!

I found this to decode your B64 protobuf: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode. I also share this with the Google team.

I'm unfamiliar with Workflows but had a quick look and think that there's no way to unmarshal the protobuf message (in the data field) using Workflows' built-in libraries.
The solution may be to call out to a service (e.g. a Cloud Run) that unmarshals the EntityEventData (the schema for the data field) and returns the (JSON?) result to your Workflow.
I do something similar albeit use Firestore native (not Datastore) where CRUD events trigger EventArc but my receivers are deployed to a Kubernetes cluster.
Google provides proto schemas for Cloud Events in google-cloudevents and stubs (or you can use protoc) for e.g. Go for e.g. datastoredata
By way of example using your message:
GOOGLEAPIS="/path/to/googleapis"
CLOUDEVENTS="/path/to/google-cloudevents/proto"

# Using your JSON message
more event.json \
| jq -r .data \
| base64 --decode --wrap=0 \
| protoc \
--decode=google.events.cloud.datastore.v1.EntityEventData \
--proto_path=${GOOGLEAPIS} \
--proto_path=${CLOUDEVENTS} \
${CLOUDEVENTS}/google/events/cloud/datastore/v1/events.proto

value {
  entity {
    key {
      partition_id {
        project_id: "e~firecms-demo-27150"
      }
      path {
        kind: "products"
        name: "0rO536qqGwsG7UHKSRsc"
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "added_on"
      value {
        timestamp_value {
          seconds: 1712099307
          nanos: 820000000
        }
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "amazon_link"
      value {
        null_value: NULL_VALUE
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "available"
      value {
        boolean_value: false
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "available_locales"
      value {
        array_value {
          values {
            string_value: "es"
            exclude_from_indexes: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "brand"
      value {
        string_value: "vrvr"
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "category"
      value {
        null_value: NULL_VALUE
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "currency"
      value {
        string_value: "DOL"
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "description"
      value {
        null_value: NULL_VALUE
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "images"
      value {
        array_value {
        }
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "json_field"
      value {
        entity_value {
        }
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "main_image"
      value {
        string_value: "images/p7stp_photo-1531746020798-e6953c6e8e04.avif"
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "name"
      value {
        string_value: "ccc"
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "price"
      value {
        null_value: NULL_VALUE
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "public"
      value {
        boolean_value: false
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "publisher"
      value {
        entity_value {
          properties {
            key: "external_id"
            value {
              null_value: NULL_VALUE
              exclude_from_indexes: true
            }
          }
          properties {
            key: "name"
            value {
              null_value: NULL_VALUE
              exclude_from_indexes: true
            }
          }
        }
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "related_products"
      value {
        array_value {
        }
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "tags"
      value {
        array_value {
        }
      }
    }
    properties {
      key: "uppercase_name"
      value {
        string_value: "CCC"
        exclude_from_indexes: true
      }
    }
  }
  update_time {
    seconds: 1712099307
    nanos: 862367000
  }
  create_time {
    seconds: 1712099307
    nanos: 862367000
  }
}


